# Sort dataframe by first column, Pandas

Tags: sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with one column, which I would like to sort. 
Typing following code gives me a sorted dataframe:

```
sort = tst.sort(["Mean"], ascending = False)

                Mean
SIMULATION          
Sim_758     1.351917
Sim_215     1.072942
Sim_830     0.921284
Sim_295     0.870272
Sim_213     0.845990
Sim_440     0.822394
```

This will be part of a function, which will be applied to other dataframes. For this reason I need to sort the dataframe without mentioning the column name "mean".

Is there a way to sort a dataframe by the values of a column, only indicating the position of the column?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you can select first column by `tst.columns[0]`, better is use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) because `sort` return warning:

> FutureWarning: sort(columns=....) is deprecated, use sort_values(by=.....)

```
sort = tst.sort_values(tst.columns[0], ascending = False)
```

---

```
print (tst)
                Mean
SIMULATION          
Sim_213     0.845990
Sim_758     1.351917
Sim_830     0.921284
Sim_295     0.870272
Sim_215     1.072942
Sim_830     0.921284
Sim_295     0.870272
Sim_440     0.822394

print (tst.columns[0])
Mean

sort = tst.sort_values(tst.columns[0], ascending = False)
print (sort)
                Mean
SIMULATION          
Sim_758     1.351917
Sim_215     1.072942
Sim_830     0.921284
Sim_830     0.921284
Sim_295     0.870272
Sim_295     0.870272
Sim_213     0.845990
Sim_440     0.822394
```